# Periodogram Formula for sampling noise

Tags: noise, power-spectral-density, periodogram

The formula I know for the periodogram is
$$I\left(f\right)=\frac{1}{NT}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\left|x\left[n\right]\exp\left(-2\pi fjnT\right)\right|^2$$
but for this one question I have which states that $N$ number of noise samples $x=\left(x_{1},x_{2}....,x_{N}\right)$ with sampling period of $T=N\Delta t$ the periodogram with even $N$ is $\frac{2 \Delta t}{N}\left|X_{k}\right|^2$ where $k=1,.....,N/2 -1$ is there a different formula I should use ?

Comment: Please correct that formula. As it stands, the periodogram would be frequency-independent, which clearly is not what we expect from a periodogram.